# How to call a sql function inside a javascript file? asp.net c#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I'm developing a calendar which takes entries from a sql database.
Inside the javascript file the calendar is builded programatically and I hardcoded the code  when it generates the calendar cell within the day(in this case is the var counter), I just need to put the query inside the function

JavaScript File

```
  if (counter == 2 //2 is the Harcoded day
        && mes == 8 //Hardcoded month
        && anio == 2014) { //Harcoded year
            PageMethods.Msg(onSuccess);
            function onSuccess(response) {
                alert(response);
            }

            htmlContent += "<div class='usuer'>Here data retrieved from DB</div>";
            htmlContent += "<div class='client'>Here data retrieved from DB</div>";
            htmlContent += "<div class='num'>Here data retrieved from DB</div>";
            htmlContent += "<div class='status'></div>";
        }
```

I create the method in the Code Behind but I dont know how to pass the Object Div to get the result of the query and set it in the Divs OR get the counter to put it in the query and get the the results of the specific days

Code Behind

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string Msg()
    {
        return "Hello world";


        string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnStr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connStr))
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(" SELECT * FROM table",myConnection);


            //Add parameters to the query
            //<--- Here? How to get counter of the javascript file? :( 


            SqlDataReader dr = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr != null)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    //<-- Here? How to set the result to the divs? :(

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: why is `return "Hello world";` on the top?

Comment: It's just for example and be sure that the call is working (it is my first funcion):c

Comment: Think of the order of what happens like this; 1. client requests page, 2. server invokes code to generate page source, 3. invocation ends, page source transmitted to client, 4. client receives page source, 5. connection from server closed, 6. client's browser interprets source, 7. `<scripts>`s are executed on the client's machine, 8. end interpretation clientside, 9. rendered page displayed to client. i.e. **for all intensive purposes** by the time _JavaScript_ is being executed (step `7`), the server-side code has already completed and the connection to the server has already been closed.

Answer (score 0):

Better use Ajax request to load data to your calendar but if you must

create a action where you prepare your data and sent it as parameter to view. <del>In view use `<script>` tags</del>  end place here your code.

Example

acction

```
    public ActionResult MyJS()
    {
        calendar = new List<DateTime>();

        calendar.Add(DateTime.Parse("2010-03-21 12:00"));
        calendar.Add(DateTime.Parse("2011-03-21 12:00"));
        calendar.Add(DateTime.Parse("2012-03-21 12:00"));

        return View(calendar);
    }
```

viev

```
@model List<DateTime>
@{
    Layout = null; // important
}
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <text> 
        alert(" @item.ToString()  ");
    </text>
}
```

and add to layout `<script src="home/myjs"></script>`